# How to store the even lines of a file to one array and the odd lines to another

Tags: c, arrays

I am given a file of DNA sequences and asked to compare all of the sequences with each other and delete the sequences that are not unique. The file I am working with is in fasta format so the odd lines are the headers and the even lines are the sequences that I want to compare. SO I am trying to store the even lines in one array and the odd lines in another. I am very new to C so I'm not sure where to begin. I figured out how to store the whole file in one array like this:

```
int main(){      
    int total_seq = 50;
    char seq[100];
    char line[total_seq][100];

    FILE *dna_file;
    dna_file = fopen("inabc.fasta", "r");

    if (dna_file==NULL){
       printf("Error");
       }
    while(fgets(seq, sizeof seq, dna_file)){
       strcpy(line[i], seq);
       printf("%s", seq);
       i++;
      }
     }

    fclose(dna_file);


    return 0;
    }
```

I was thinking I would have to incorporate some sort of code that looked like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < rows; i++){

    if (i % 2 == 0) header[i/2] = getline();
    else seq[i/2] = getline();
```

but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Could you please give me an example of the data in the file?

Am I right in thinking it'd be something like:

Header
Sequence
Header
Sequence

And so on

Perhaps you could do something like this:

```
int main(){      
int total_seq = 50;
char seq[100];
char line[total_seq][100];

FILE *dna_file;
dna_file = fopen("inabc.fasta", "r");

if (dna_file==NULL){
   printf("Error");
   }

// Put this in an else statement
int counter = 1;
while(fgets(seq, sizeof seq, dna_file)){
   // If counter is odd
      // Place next line read in headers array
   // If counter is even
      // Place next line read in sequence array
   // Increment counter
 }
// Now you have all the sequences & headers. Remove any duplicates
// Foreach number of elements in 'sequence' array - referenced by, e.g. 'j' where 'j' starts at 0
   // Foreach number of elements in 'sequence' array - referenced by 'k' - Where 'k' Starts at 'j + 1'
      // IF (sequence[j] != '~') So if its not our chosen escape character
         // IF (sequence[j] == sequence[k]) (I think you'd have to use strcmp for this?)
            // SET sequence[k] = '~';
            // SET header[k] = '~';
         // END IF
      // END IF
   // END FOR
// END FOR
}

// You'd then need an algorithm to run through the arrays. If a '~' is found. Move the following non tilda/sequence down to its position, and so on.

// EDIT: Infact. It would probably be easier if when writing back to file, just ignore/don't write if sequence[x] == '~' (where 'x' iterates through all)

// Finally write back to file

fclose(dna_file);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: it is in fasta format so it looks like this:

>header 1 
SEQUENCE1 
>header2 
SEQUENCE2 
>header 3 
SEQUENCE3 

and so forth. Im not sure how to get all of those on a separate line in this comment but this sample file would have 6 lines

Comment: Yes that's exactly what it looks like. So I need two separate arrays, header[] and seq[]. Thank you!

Comment: This seems like a good approach, thank you! How exactly do you place the line in a header? I thought fgets() placed all of the lines from dan_file into the array seq[], so am I just moving the odd elements of the seq[] array into the new array header[]? Is this a good time to use getline()?

Comment: I would store the line returned in each phase of the while loop in a temp string variable. then based on the odd/even condition copy it to the relevant array. is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

To store the even lines of a file to one array and the odd lines to another,
read each `char` and swap output files when `'\n'` encountered.

```
void Split(FILE *even, FILE* odd, FILE *source) {
  int evenflag = 1;
  int ch;
  while ((ch = fgetc(source)) != EOF) {
    if (evenflag) {
      fputc(ch, even);
    } else {
      fputc(ch, odd);
    }
    if (ch == '\n') {
      evenflag = !evenflag;
    }
  }
}
```

It is not clear if this post also requires code to do the unique filtering step.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that because it is a fasta file, the program knows that ">header" is one line and the sequence begins on the next line. ">" is treated as a newline character so the program knows that anything between ">header1" and the next ">" is one sequence.

Comment: In your example, are "even", "odd", and "source" three separate files or three different arrays? I just started with C so I'm a little confused.

Comment: @katiesf0106 Yes 3, `dna_file = fopen("inabc.fasta", "r");` opens the file and would be used in `FILE *odd = fopen("odd.txt", "w"); FILE *even = fopen("even.txt", "w"); Split(even, odd, dna_file);`

Answer (score 0):

First: write a function that counts the number of newline (`\n`) characters in the file.
Then write a function that searches for the n-th newline
Last, write a function to go through and read from one '\n' to the next.

Alternately, you could just go online and read about string parsing.